# I'm trying to call a 2 dimensional array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, class, methods

We are trying to use the array to store the locations and then call them in the if else statements in the first class. We want to be able to call the grid locations so we do not have to type the description of the room in the if else statements.

```
package ProjectTwo;   
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProjectTwo {
    // ----------------------------------------
    // Main method, calls location (loc) method, which controls navigation
    // ----------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args){
       loc();
    }
    // This method allows the user to view a list of actions that are used throughout the game
    public static void help() {
        System.out.println("Enter the letter 'n' to move north, the letter 's' to move south, or type the word 'quit' to end the game. Also, you can enter the letter 'm' to see an image of the map.");
    }
    // -------------------------------------
    // Loc method
    // Prints on-load message (intro)
    // Defines global variables
    // -------------------------------------
    public static void loc() {
        location.locMove();

        int location = 0;
        System.out.println("The Search" + "\n" + "\n" + "You have awoken in a laboratory. There is a door to your north and a door to your south." + "/n+" +  "Enter 'n' and 's' to navigate, or type 'quit' to end the game. Also, enter the letter 'h'.");

        String userInput = new String();
        boolean stillPlaying = true;
    // ------------------------------------ 
    // Moves player while user is still playing
    // Tells user his/her location  
    // ------------------------------------
    while (stillPlaying) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = scan.nextLine();
        if (location == 0){
            if (userInput.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("You entered the dungeon.");
                location = 1; // Moves user from location 0 to 1

            }
                else if (userInput.equals("s")) {
                System.out.println("You cannot move south.");
                location = 0; // Keeps user at location 0
                } else if (userInput.equals("quit")){
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
                    stillPlaying = false;
        }
                else if (userInput.equals("h")) {
                    help(); // calls the help method
                }
                else if (userInput.equals("m")) {
                    map(); // calls the map method
                }
            else {
                System.out.println("Command not understood.");  

            } 

        }   else if (location == 1) {
            if (userInput.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("You have escaped out the back door of the dungeon.");
                location = 2; // Moves user from location 1 to location 2
            }
            else if(userInput.equals("s")) {
                System.out.println("You're back in the laboratory.");
                location = 0; // Moves user from location 1 to location 0
            } else if (userInput.equals("quit")){
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
                stillPlaying = false;
            }
            else if (userInput.equals("h")) {
                help(); // calls the help method
            }
            else if (userInput.equals("m")) {
                map(); // calls the map method
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Command not understood");

            }
        }

        else if (location == 2) {
            if (userInput.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("You cannot go that way...yet!");
                location = 2; // Lets the user know that they cannot go that way

            }
            else if (userInput.equals("s")) {
                System.out.println("You're back in the dungeon");
                location = 1; // Mover from location 2 to location 1
                }
        else if (userInput.equals("quit")){
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
                    stillPlaying = false;
                    }
        else if (userInput.equals("h")) {
            help(); // calls help method
        }
        else if (userInput.equals("m")) {
            map(); // calls map method
        }
        else {
                System.out.println("Command not understood.");

                }
        }


    }
}
}

//This is our main class
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

// This is our class with the 2d array

```
package ProjectTwo;
public class location {

        public int location;
        public String name;
        public static String message;

        public location(String name, int location, String message){
            this.name = name;
            this.location = location;
            this.message = message;

            System.out.println(message);
        }
        public static void locMove() {
        location [][] grid = new location[4][4]; 
        {
            grid [1][0] = new location("LABORATORY", 0, "You're in the lab.");
            grid [2][0] = new location("DUNGEON", 1, "You entered the dungeon.");
            grid [3][0] = new location("COURTYARD ENTRANCE",2,"You have left the dungeon out the backdoor. Either head east and search the courtyard maze, or travel north back to the dungeon");
            grid [3][1] = new location("FIRST PATH", 3,"You have now entered the courtyard, either continue east or move north.");
            grid [3][2] = new location("DEADEND", 4,"You have reached a deadend that has a Magic Shop. Go inside and explore it.");
            grid [3][3] = new location ("MAGIC SHOP", 5, "Search around the Magic Shop and see what there is. When you're done searching continue through the maze.");
            grid [2][1] = new location("SECOND PATH",6,"Search the surroundings for items that will help you get into the locked room, then keep moving.");
            grid [2][2] = new location("END MAZE", 7, "You've made it to the end of the courtyard. There seems to be a cave in the distance; go check it out.");
            grid [1][2] = new location("CAVE",8,"Explore the cave to find the remaining items that will lead to your freedom.");
            grid [0][0] = new location("EXIT",9,"This room will lead to your freedom, but you need the three essential items that will open this door.");
        }
        while (grid.equals(0)) {
            System.out.println(message.toString());
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have an instance of the location class in the `ProjectTwo` class? Also, your code is so badly formatted its upsetting.

Comment: Instantiate location class inside ProjectTwo class and then you can get the array access using the location object's reference variable. I would suggest getters and setters inside your location class so that you don't directly modify your array data.

Comment: Move your import statement out of your classbody, for one...

Comment: It appears (correct me if I'm wrong) that you're asking people to fix your homework. Rather than pasting all your (not very nicely formatted) code and asking for a spoon-fed solution, why don't you try breaking your problem down to a small chunk and ask a more abstract question whose solution might later benefit others?

Comment: actually what we are doing is asking how to call an array from a different class, and if we need to use an extender to call another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you say but look your code, think this is really fits your code without changing much but just my opinion:

*"try using, **L**ocation not  **l**ocation to name classes but not nesesario"*

> package ProjectTwo;
>
> public class location {

In Your Class location:

```
//Your other code

public static location [][] locMove() {  // <--- change void for location [][]
location [][] grid = new location[4][4]; 
        {
            grid [1][0] = new location("LABORATORY", 0, "You're in the lab.");
            grid [2][0] = new location("DUNGEON", 1, "You entered the dungeon.");
            grid [3][0] = new location("COURTYARD ENTRANCE",2,"You have left the dungeon out the backdoor. Either head east and search the courtyard maze, or travel north back to the dungeon");
            grid [3][1] = new location("FIRST PATH", 3,"You have now entered the courtyard, either continue east or move north.");
            grid [3][2] = new location("DEADEND", 4,"You have reached a deadend that has a Magic Shop. Go inside and explore it.");
            grid [3][3] = new location ("MAGIC SHOP", 5, "Search around the Magic Shop and see what there is. When you're done searching continue through the maze.");
            grid [2][1] = new location("SECOND PATH",6,"Search the surroundings for items that will help you get into the locked room, then keep moving.");
            grid [2][2] = new location("END MAZE", 7, "You've made it to the end of the courtyard. There seems to be a cave in the distance; go check it out.");
            grid [1][2] = new location("CAVE",8,"Explore the cave to find the remaining items that will lead to your freedom.");
            grid [0][0] = new location("EXIT",9,"This room will lead to your freedom, but you need the three essential items that will open this door.");
        }
    while (grid.equals(0)) {
        System.out.println(message.toString());
    }

 return grid;
 }

 //Your other code
```

In your other class:

```
package ProjectTwo;   
public class ProjectTwo {
    //your other code
    location [][] testGrid = null; //<--- add variable
    //your other code

    public static void main(String[] args){
           loc();
}
   //your other code

    public static void loc() {

        testGrid = location.locMove();

        //testGrid <-- this your array
  //your other code
```

I have not test, but I think it can work, but not the way I usually do, I hope you can help.

P.S: You could look at this, if you want https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with the comments about code style and formatting. Anyway here are the suggestions how you can refactor your code.

Probably the simplest way to avoid writing lots of if-else construction is to use switches. You loc() code might look something like that (I would also move duplicated h/m/quit commands to a single place):

Solution 1:

```
...

while (stillPlaying) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    userInput = scan.nextLine();

    switch (userInput) {
        case "quit":
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
            stillPlaying = false;
            break;

        case "h":
            help(); // calls the help method
            break;

        case "m":
            map(); // calls the map method
            break;

        case "n":
        case "s":
            switch (location) {
                case 0:
                    switch (userInput) {
                        case "n":
                            System.out.println("You entered the dungeon.");
                            location = 1; // Moves user from location 0 to 1
                            break;

                        case "s":
                            System.out.println("You cannot move south.");
                            location = 0; // Keeps user at location 0
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    switch (userInput) {
                        case "n":
                            System.out.println("You have escaped out the back door of the dungeon.");
                            location = 2; // Moves user from location 1 to location 2
                            break;

                        case "s":
                            System.out.println("You're back in the laboratory.");
                            location = 0; // Moves user from location 1 to location 0
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    switch (userInput) {
                        case "n":
                            System.out.println("You cannot go that way...yet!");
                            location = 2; // Lets the user know that they cannot go that way
                            break;

                        case "s":
                            System.out.println("You're back in the dungeon");
                            location = 1; // Mover from location 2 to location 1
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("no such location");
            }
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Command not understood.");

    }
}

...
```

However the better way is to try to encapsulate the locations-commands-actions stuff to a different classes. That how it might look:

Solution 2:

```
public static interface Action {
    // return the next location or an error
    int action();
}

public static class LocationsMap {
    public Map<Integer, Map<String, Action>> locations = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerAction(int location, String userInput, Action action) {
        Map<String, Action> actionsMap = locations.get(location);
        if (actionsMap == null) {
            actionsMap = new HashMap<>();
            locations.put(location, actionsMap);
        }

        actionsMap.put(userInput, action);
    }

    public int executeAction(int location, String userInput) {
        Map<String, Action> currentLocation = locations.get(location);
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        Action currentAction = currentLocation.get(userInput);
        if (currentAction == null) {
            return -2;
        }

        return currentAction.action(); // move to next location
    }
}
```

then you can define your actions (per location and user input) like that:

```
...

public static LocationsMap locationsMap = new LocationsMap();
static {
    // location 0
    locationsMap.registerAction(0, "n", new Action() {
        @Override
        public int action() {
            System.out.println("You entered the dungeon.");
            return  1; // Moves user from location 0 to 1
        }
    });
    locationsMap.registerAction(0, "s", new Action() {
        @Override
        public int action() {
            System.out.println("You cannot move south.");
            return  0; // Keeps user at location 0
        }
    });

    // location 1
    locationsMap.registerAction(1, "n", new Action() {
        @Override
        public int action() {
            System.out.println("You have escaped out the back door of the dungeon.");
            return 2; // Moves user from location 1 to location 2
        }
    });
    locationsMap.registerAction(1, "s", new Action() {
        @Override
        public int action() {
            System.out.println("You're back in the laboratory.");
            return 0; // Moves user from location 1 to location 0
        }
    });

    // location 2
    locationsMap.registerAction(2, "n", new Action() {
        @Override
        public int action() {
            System.out.println("You cannot go that way...yet!");
            return 2; // Lets the user know that they cannot go that way
        }
    });
    locationsMap.registerAction(2, "s", new Action() {
        @Override
        public int action() {
            System.out.println("You're back in the dungeon");
            return 1; // Mover from location 2 to location 1
        }
    });
}

...
```

and then the code in the loc() function will look like that:

```
...

while (stillPlaying) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    userInput = scan.nextLine();

    switch (userInput) {
        case "quit":
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
            stillPlaying = false;
            break;

        case "h":
            help(); // calls the help method
            break;

        case "m":
            map(); // calls the map method
            break;

        default:
            int actionResult = locationsMap.executeAction(location, userInput);

            if (actionResult == -1) {
                System.out.println("no such location");
                break;
            }

            if (actionResult == -2) {
                System.out.println("Command not understood.");
                break;
            }

            location = actionResult; // move to next location

    }
}

...
```

That is not the best solution, but it is much better and readable.
I would also define an enum for locations instead of using ints.

Also you can think about storing this locations-inputs-actions information in some file, parse it and then use in the app/game, but that will be more complicated to implement.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it very much. Im going to do some research on enums to understand them better.